# UITableView row action is not called

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I created UITableView with 1 section and 3 rows in it. Text in each row is hardcoded and I need to call specific actions by tapping each row.
Why UITableView delegae method func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) is not called in following code?

```
@IBOutlet weak var tbvSetting: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tbvSetting.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Countries"
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Managers"
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Customers"
    default:
        break
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

Thanks for hints.

Comment: Did you implement the `UITableViewDelegate`? The functions that are getting called are called on the `UITableViewDataSource`. You need to implement both.

Comment: Yes, I did - this is my class declaration class vcSettings: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource and method func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup up `self` as the `delegate` of the `tableView`.
You can do it in Storyboard(which seems like you are using) or in code as:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tbvSetting.delegate = self
    tbvSetting.reloadData()
}
```

Since, this has not been setup yet, even though tableView cells are getting `selected`, the OS is unaware of who is the handler of the selection gesture.

Comment: OMG!!! I thought I did in in IB already but I forgot. Now it works, thanks a lot @ystack.